# How to show that $\iint_{S}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=0$ with the vector field $\vec{F}=\big\langle0,0,z\big\rangle$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:** If $S$ is the cylindrical surface parametrized by $\phi(\theta,u)=(\cos{(\theta)},\sin{(\theta)},u)$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $u\in[0,1]$, then $\iint_{S}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=0$ for the vector field $\vec{F}=\big\langle0,0,z\big\rangle$.

**Solution:**

$\iint_{S}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=\iint_{D}\vec{F}(\phi(\theta,u))\cdot \vec{n}\ dA$

I know that $\vec{F}(\phi(\theta,u))=F(\cos{(\theta)},\sin{(\theta)},u)=\big\langle0,0,u\big\rangle$

But I don't know how to get $\vec{n}$. What it is?

Answer (score 2):

$\vec n$ is the standard normal vector to the surface $S$. So you compute $n$ as $\mathbf T_\theta\times\mathbf T_u$ where $\mathbf T_\theta$ is tangent vector in the $\theta$ direction (i.e. $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta}$), and $\mathbf T_u$ is tangent vector in the $u$ direction (i.e. $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u}$). So the calculation can also be written as $$\iint_S\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\iint_D\mathbf F(\phi(\theta,u))\cdot(\mathbf T_\theta\times\mathbf T_u)d\theta\,du$$

Comment: $(\mathbf T_\theta\times\mathbf T_u)$ is $\big\langle-\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0\big\rangle$ ?

Comment: @InfZero I just did the cross product and got $\mathbf T_\theta\times\mathbf T_u=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0)$. But even if my calculation is wrong, the zero in the $z$-component makes the integral calculation very easy.

Answer (score 1):

$d\vec{S} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} \  du \ dv$ this will be in the direction perpendicular to the $\vec{F}$ which you are given.

Comment: notice the partial derivative vectors$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$  point tangent to the surface which $u,v$ serve as parameters, it follows their cross-product points in the normal direction.

Comment: @Qwerty, thanks.